# TDBGrid - Synchronisation or display problem

Tags: delphi, dbexpress, tdbgrid

I am facing a very strange problem in one of my programs. I have a `TSQLConnection` followed by two `TSQLQUery`, `TDataSetProvider`, `TClientDataSet` and `TDataSource`. Its a Master-Detail structure.

The `TDataSource` of the detail query has an additional column with one lookup property of the master query. (Think of something like 'ProductID, ProductName, GroupName' where GroupName comes from the master query)

Then I have a DBGrid which has the `TDataSource` of the detail query as Source. It diplays most parts correctly, but the field that is a lookup from the master-query, sometimes does not show. Sometimes means in this case, i scroll down in the DBGrid, and up again, then its gone. I scroll down and up one more time, and its shown.

For debugging I added a `TDBLookupComboBox` with the same source as the DBGrid, but the ComboBox always shows the correct value for this field.

Thanks for any help on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `LookupCash` property of the lookup column to `true`, I think this will solve the problem.